# Similar RESTfull services in AngularJS

Tags: django, angularjs, rest

I started learning AngularJS recently, and wanna combine it with Django RESTfull framework.
What I got now is I finished the Django-side work, I got the following URLs:

xxxxx/object_a/   (GET to get objects, POST to save object)
xxxxx/object_a/id (PUT to update object, DELETE to remove the object)

similarly,

xxxxx/object_b/
xxxxx/object_b/id

...and so on

As you could see, all of these URLs share the same query methods.

So now back to the AngularJS side.
I could write several services to handle each objects, but I'm not sure if this is the best practice or this is the correct "AngularJS" way to do this.
I tried something like this:

```
app.factory('Resource', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return function(url, params, methods) {
        var defaults = {
            'create': { method: 'POST' },
            'delete': { method: 'DELETE' },
            'update': { method: 'PUT' },
            'get': { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
        }

        methods = angular.extend(defaults, methods);
        var resource = $resource(url, params, methods);

        resource.prototype.$save = function() {
            if(!this.id) {
                return this.$create();
            }
            else {
                return this.$update();
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

It looks better for me, but I don't know neither if this is the "AngularJS" way to do the work, nor how to continue to build services using this for each object, so I'm here for advices.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!